# Drop percentage of a dataframe [pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with a very long tail and wish to sample only 90% of the data.

```
city          score
bangkok       60
kl            20
sydney        10
melbourne     5
dhaka         5
```

should be:

```
city          score
bangkok       60
kl            20
sydney        10
```

Comment: is the data which is filtered out based on score?

Comment: Yep, that's right

Comment: score above 90%?

Comment: Yes, above 90% of the cumulative total. Hope that is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, sort the values that you want to filter the highest 90% of the data

```
df.sort_values('score', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Then, you calculate the cumulative sum and divide with the total in order to make your filtering conditions (you can replace `0.9` with your custom limit)

```
df = df[df['score'].cumsum() / df['score'].sum() < 0.9]
```

Now `df` looks like

```
city          score
bangkok       60
kl            20
sydney        10
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe need count score by division of `sum` and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for better performance in filtered rows:

```
a = 0.9
df = df[df['score'].div(df['score'].sum()) >= 1 - a].sort_values('score', ascending=False)
```

Or:

```
df = df[df['score'].div(df['score'].sum()) >= 0.1].sort_values('score', ascending=False)
```

---

```
print (df)
      city  score
0  bangkok     60
1       kl     20
2   sydney     10
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['score'].div(df['score'].sum()))
0    0.60
1    0.20
2    0.10
3    0.05
4    0.05
Name: score, dtype: float64
```